# Return MongoDB/Mongoose Aggregation Match First Letter

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, nosql

I am trying to return an array of results using `Mongoose` and `mongoDB` in `Node.js`.

I have something like this to match every header that starts with `za` for example:

```
Model.aggregate(
        { $project: { firstLetter : { $substr : ["$header", 0, 2] }}},
        { $match: { firstLetter : 'za' }},
        { $limit: 40 }
    );
```

But when I assign the result to a variable it is just an `Aggregate` object that I cannot identify what to do with.

Mongoose docs state:

```
The documents returned are plain javascript objects, not mongoose documents (since any shape of document can be returned).
```

Why am I not getting the results?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that you need to get the data asynchronously, which makes sense (of course).

Something like:

```
Model.aggregate(
        { $project: { firstLetter : { $substr : ["$header", 0, 2] }}},
        { $match: { firstLetter : 'za' }},
        { $limit: 40 }
    ).exec(function(err, data) {
       doSomethingWithData(data);
});
```

Hopefully can help someone else out.